# How do I get comments to be indexed?

Tags: 8, search

I'm not sure if it's actually doing this; I can't see any options for comment fields in the configuration. How can I check? Does it say explicitly somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

[Apachesolr Comments](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_comments)

> By default the apachesolr module index comments attached to the node.
>   So you can not search comments directly. This module separates
>   comments from the nodes and allows you to search them directly.

**UPDATE:**

For **search api** apply this patch

```
diff --git a/modules/callbacks.inc b/modules/callbacks.inc
index dca9e1d..e12be6a 100644
--- a/modules/callbacks.inc
+++ b/modules/callbacks.inc
@@ -80,6 +80,12 @@ function entity_metadata_comment_get_node_properties($node, array $options, $nam

     case 'comment_count_new':
       return comment_num_new($node->nid);
+
+    case 'comments':
+      $select = db_select('comment', 'c')
+        ->fields('c', array('cid'))
+        ->condition('c.nid', $node->nid);
+      return array_keys($select->execute()->fetchAllKeyed(0, 0));
   }
 }

diff --git a/modules/comment.info.inc b/modules/comment.info.inc
index 4321b4c..a9d7fe9 100644
--- a/modules/comment.info.inc
+++ b/modules/comment.info.inc
@@ -136,6 +136,13 @@ function entity_metadata_comment_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
     'setter permission' => 'administer comments',
     'type' => 'integer',
   );
+  $properties['comments'] = array(
+    'label' => t("Comments"),
+    'type' => 'list<comment>',
+    'description' => t("The node comments."),
+    'getter callback' => 'entity_metadata_comment_get_node_properties',
+    'computed' => TRUE,
+  );
   $properties['comment_count'] = array(
     'label' => t("Comment count"),
     'description' => t("The number of comments posted on a node."),
```

Taken from the source https://drupal.org/node/1414688#comment-7037540 and also worth looking at this http://blog.merge.nl/shorts/search-api-indexing-nodes-including-comments

Comment: Might be worth mentioning it's currently in dev...

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not using the Apachsolr module, I'm using Search API Solr.

Comment: @Clive  I updated my answer

Comment: An Updated answer to Drupal 8 would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8 I had to write custom properties to get my comments into the index.

I followed this documentation https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/search-api/developer-documentation/create-custom-fields-using-a-custom-processor

And than queried my Entity in addFieldValues() Method.

Like

```
$object = $item->getOriginalObject()->getValue();
$comment_ids = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('comment')->getQuery()
 ->condition('comment_type', '<comment_type>')
 ->condition('entity_id', $object->id())
 ->execute();
$comments = $this->getEntityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('comment')
  ->loadMultiple($comment_ids);
$fields = $this->getFieldsHelper()
  ->filterForPropertyPath($item->getFields(), NULL, '<my_property_definition>');
foreach ($fields as $field) {
  /** @var \Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment $answer */
  foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    $field->addValue($comment->comment_body->value);
  }
}
```